# How can I assign a layer to tiles on an individual level?

Tags: unity, tiles, platformer

I've just started out with my first game in Unity. It's a simple 2D Platformer with a tile-based level.

[image]

When coding in the movement, I used the Physics2D.OverlapCircle() and an empty to check whether my player was touching the ground. However, I need to use a layer to make sure only the ground is detected.

*my code below*

```
//fixed update used for physics calculations
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //right or left arrows being pressed
    float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector2 moveDir = new Vector2(moveX * playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.velocity = moveDir;
}
 
//update used for spacebar input and force
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce*Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    //is my circle overlapping any other colliders
    Collider2D collider =  Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feet.position, checkRadius, groundLayer);
    Debug.Log(collider); 
}
```

When I tried assigning layers to my tiles, I couldn't find a way to do it.

I would be really grateful if anyone could show me how to, or if anyone can tell me a more efficient way to deal with jumping in a 2D platformer.

Comment: Have you considered placing a second tilemap under the same grid for your non-walkable tiles?

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's working wonderfully right now.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your problem! Want to write up your solution as an Answer below to help future users?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Assuming you are using tiles as prefab. So just change the layer of walkable tiles in the main prefab.

Also, you can manually add the layer via script.[Referance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html)

Make a tile script and add it to the tile prefab.

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like they're using a tilemap component, not individual prefabs per tile.

Comment: Yes I am using the tilemap system. Thank you for your help anyway.